# javaScript for/loop scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have written this bit of code that sums the values of array. Can some one please explain why I'm getting undefined in the last console.log statement.

```
var array = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    sum = array[i] + sum; 
}

console.log(sum);
console.log(array[i]);
```

Comment: Simply console logging `i` would give you the answer.

Comment: Hint: if `i < array.length` returns true, you'd still be in your for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the loop performed `i++` and now `i` is equal to `array.length`.

JavaScript returns the primitive value `undefined` when you're trying to access object properties that were not previously defined.

The array however is only filled between places `0` and `array.length - 1` since JavaScript arrays are 0 based.